# Polarisation of a cation by an anion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Shriver and Atkins' Inorganic Chemistry (5th edition) explains amphotericity of the oxides of the heavier elements in Groups III, IV and V by high covalent character of the bonds made by the elements.

It states: "The onset of amphoterism correlates with a significant degree of covalent character in the bonds formed by the elements, either because the metal ion is strongly polarising (as for Be) or because the metal ion is polarised by the O atom attached to it (as for Sb)."

I have heard of many explanations using the polarising power of cations but never have I heard the "reverse", which is the polarising power of anions. Polarisation of an anion by a highly-polarising cation means that the cation distorts the electron cloud of the anion strongly. How would that work for the polarisation of a cation by an anion?

Comment: "A useful rule of thumb is that small cations, which are not easily polarized, are
hard and form complexes with small anions. Large cations are more polarizable and are soft." Later the book said similar things about hard/soft acids. I have the same question as you.